# check mimetype in javascript based on two condition

Tags: javascript

I am using a function in my javascript file in which the function is called onchange event.

```
function restrictUpload(event,fileID,path){
var files=event.target.files;
var mimeType=files[0].type;
 if(mimeType!="image/jpeg" || mimeType!="image/png"){
 console.log(mimeType);
 alert("Upload only JPEG,JPG,PNG");
 $('#'+fileID).val('');
 document.getElementById("userPhoto").src = path+"/default.png";
 }
}
```

When I upload jpeg image it shows alert, pdf files and png files also alerts. I need the files is not jpeg and png format to go inside the if condition.

Comment: each mime type you get will be either different from `image/jpeg` or `image/png` (or both). You should adjust your condition there.

Comment: and mimeType!=="image/jpeg"

Comment: @Sirko If I put only one condition it works fine. Like `if(mimeType!="image/jpeg"){
 ...
}` but I need to check png also..

Comment: @ChrisChen also tried not helps. any other method..

Comment: I'd probably do it the other way around: `if ( [ 'image/jpeg', 'image/png' ].includes( mimeType ) ) { ... } else { ... }`. You also output the `mimeType` itself - have you checked the value you get is what you expect?

Comment: @Sirko I'm getting image/png if I upload png and image/jpeg for jpg files

Comment: @Sirko I added ! symbol and your idea works `if (! [ 'image/jpeg', 'image/png' ].includes( mimeType ) ) { ... } else { ... }`... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the Sirko's comment I made this answer.

```
if (! [ 'image/jpeg', 'image/png' ].includes( mimeType ) )
  { ... }
else 
  { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want the mimeType to be differente from jpeg AND png?

```
if(mimeType!="image/jpeg" && mimeType!="image/png"){
 ...
}
```

Comment: Im am uploading only one file at a time. yours also not worked